# fill in list in multiple steps

Tags: python, list, iteration

Lets assume you have a list with y poisitions (0 for sake of this question).  If y = 10:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

You want to fill adjacent positions up to a given value x and append it to an empty list.  If x = 4:

```
[[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0], ... , [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]]
```

I made that occur through this function:

```
def permutations(number=4, limit=10):

    perms = [] 

    if type(number) == int:
        a = -1
        b = a + number
        while b < limit:
            a+=1
            b = a + number
            start = [0 for x in range(limit)]
            for i in range(a, b):
                start[i] = 1
            perms.append(start)
```

This is fine, but if I want to do the same thing, but pass a tuple instead of an integer I'd like the output to be:

if number = (4,3):

```
[[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0], [1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0], [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1],
 [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0], [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1],
 [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1]]
```

The 0 between the two groupings of 1's is necessary the first value of the tuple corresponds to the number of 1's in the first grouping, and the second value of the tuple corresponds to the number of 1's in the second grouping.  Ideally this function would work with tuples that have more than 2 values.

This idea is a little challenging to get across so please let me know if you need any clarification.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you only going to be dealing with pairs or could your tuple be (4,3,2)?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, when I said "Ideally this function would work with tuples that have more than 2 values".  I'd like it to work with something like (4,3,2) as well!

Comment: The way I would think about this is you have 2 `lists` `[1,1,1,1,0]` and `[1,1,1]` or 3 lists you have `[1,1,1,1,0]` `[1,1,1,0]` and `[1,1]`.  Now consider all of the permutations of 0s, equal to the number of remaining spaces, filling in those gaps between those lists ie if you have 2 available spaces you could put both between, both before, both after etc.

Comment: So in other words, you're placing the 0, not the 1's?

Comment: Correct. You could save them into lists and then mash them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach I can think of is to generate all possible combinations of 1 and 0, and filter out all of the ones that don't have the right grouping lengths.

```
import itertools

def permutations(tup, limit=10):
    for candidate in itertools.product([0,1], repeat=limit):
        segment_lengths = [len(list(b)) for a,b in itertools.groupby(candidate) if a == 1]
        if tup == tuple(segment_lengths):
            yield candidate

for seq in permutations((4, 3), 10):
    print seq
```

Result:

```
(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Note that this is very slow for large values of `limit` - it has to evaluate 2^limit candidate sequences. Not bad for limit = 10; only 1024 candidates need to be evaluated. But it quickly grows into the millions and beyond for larger limits.

---

Edit: Inspired by user2097159's excellent comment, here's an approach with better run time.

```
import itertools

"""Finds all non-negative integer sequences whose sum equals `total`, and who have `size` elements."""
def possible_sums(total, size):
    if total == 0:
        yield [0]*size
        return
    if size == 1:
        yield [total]
        return
    for i in range(total+1):
        left = [i]
        for right in possible_sums(total-i, size-1):
            yield left + right

"""
combines two lists a and b in order like:
[a[0], b[0], a[1], b[1]...]

"""
def interleave(a,b):
    result = []
    for pair in itertools.izip_longest(a,b):
        for item in pair:
            if item is not None:
                result.append(item)
    return result

"""flattens a list of lists into a one dimensional list"""
def flatten(seq):
    return [x for item in seq for x in item]

def permutations(tup, limit):
    one_segments = [[1]*size for size in tup]
    for i in range(len(tup)-1):
        one_segments[i].append(0)
    remaining_zeroes = limit - sum(tup) - len(tup) + 1
    assert remaining_zeroes >= 0, "not enough room to separate ranges!"
    for gap_sizes in possible_sums(remaining_zeroes, len(tup)+1):
        zero_segments = [[0]*size for size in gap_sizes]
        yield flatten(interleave(zero_segments, one_segments))

for seq in permutations((4, 3), 10):
    print seq
```

Comment: Well, I'm glad I asked because I am not familiar enough with itertools to have thought of that on my own.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: darn, I was writing exactly this! (at least the `possible_sums` part) (except with making sure not to have `total == 0`, as this generates lots of unnecessary elements)

Comment: To flatten a list of lists you can use the fact that `sum` simply uses the `+` operator which is defined for lists and do: sum(list_of_lists, [])

Comment: Nicely done @Kevin.  Didn't have time to do this before having to rush out the door yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all list recursively.

```
F(tup, limit) = 
[1, 1, ...1, 0] combine with all solutions of F(tup[1:], limit - len(tup[1]) - 1)
[0, 1 ,1 , ... 1, 0] combine with all solutions of F(tup[1:], limit - len(tup[1]) - 2)
.
.
.
```

1. if tup is empty return a list of zero
2. if sum(tup) + len(tup) - 1 > limit, return an empty list since there is no solution.
   e.g. `permutations((4,3,2), 10)` shall return `[]`
3. Otherwise, enumerating how many prefix zero there will be:

   4. Generate prefix list which is `[0, 0, 0 .. 0, 1, 1, ... 1, 0]` The number of `1`s is the value of first item in the tuple. Append additional 0 if it's not the last item of the tuple.
   5. Call the function recursively for the rest element in the tuple to solve the similar sub-problem
   6. Combine the prefix list with each solution of the sub-problem

Here is the code:

```
def permutations(tup, limit=100):
    if len(tup) <= 0:
        return [[0] * limit]
    minimum_len = sum(tup) + len(tup) - 1
    if minimum_len > limit:
        return []

    perms = []
    for prefix_zero in range(0, limit - minimum_len + 1):
        prefix = [0] * prefix_zero + [1] * tup[0]
        if len(tup) > 1:
            prefix += [0]
        suffix_list = permutations(tup[1:], limit - len(prefix))
        perms += [prefix + suffix for suffix in suffix_list] #combine the solutions
    return perms
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution creates all permutations of blocks of ones (a list defined by each entry in the tuple) with blocks of zeros (lists of length one) for the extra padding.

```
import itertools as it

spec = (1,2,3)

nBlocks = len(spec)
nZeros = 5
totalSize = sum(spec) + nZeros+1-nBlocks

blocks = [[1,]*s + [0,] for s in spec]
zeros = [[0,],]*(nZeros+1-nBlocks)

a = list(it.permutations(blocks + zeros, nZeros+1))
b = [list(it.chain.from_iterable(l))[:-1] for l in a]

for l in b:
    print l
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple non-recursive generator solution without `itertools`:

```
def fill_sequence(sequence, size):
    n_slots = size - len(sequence)
    for start in xrange(n_slots + 1):
        yield [0]*start + sequence + [0]*(n_slots - start)

def all_placements(inner_sizes, outer_size):
    x, y = inner_sizes
    for margin in xrange(1, outer_size - sum(block_sizes) + 1):
        sequence = [1]*x + [0]*margin + [1]*y
        for p in fill_sequence(sequence, outer_size):
            yield p
```

So that:

```
>>> list(all_placements((4,3), 10))
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

The idea is quite simple. Suppose you fix the number of zeros between your two blocks of ones, call it the `margin`. This gives you a `4 + margin + 3` sequence. You can easily place this sequence in the larger list of zeros using the approach you took in your post. Then simply iteratively increase the margin, yielding all possible placements.

Answer (score 0):

Without using itertools.

My shot at this, should be fairly quick, but uses a **recursive** generator (python recursion depth limit, here I come...).

```
# simple test case
seqs = (1, 2, 3)
length = 10

# '0' spots count
zeros = length - (sum(seqs))
# partitions count
partitions = len(seqs) + 1


# first and last can partitions have 0 zeros
# so use a flag when we call the function or check if it's the last partition
def generate_gaps(zeros_left, partition, first=False):
    """ 
    :param zeros_left: how many zeros we can still use
    :param partition: what partition is this
    :param first: is this the first gap
    :return: all possible gaps
    """
    for gap in range((0 if first or partition == 0 else 1), zeros_left + 1):
        if partition == 0:
            if (zeros_left - gap) == 0:
                yield [gap]
        else:
            for rest in generate_gaps(zeros_left - gap, partition - 1):
                yield [gap] + rest

for gaps in generate_gaps(zeros, partitions - 1, True):
    print "using gaps: " + str(gaps)
    # merge lists
    # zip gaps (0's) and sequences (1's) - all but last gap (added to result)
    gaps_seqs = zip(gaps, seqs)
    # expand everything... magic (could be done explicitly trivially).
    result = sum(map(lambda x: [0] * x[0] + [1] * x[1], gaps_seqs)
    # last gap (truncated from zip)
    result = result + [[0] * gaps[-1]], [])
```